# Why doesn't require_all work inside a Sinatra helper?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

So I have a function `reload_config` inside a Sinatra helper module which is defined below in `helpers.rb`.

```
module Web
  module Helpers
    def reload_config
      require_all 'config/*.rb'
    end
  end
end
```

It is then loaded in `Web::Base` the recommended way using `helpers  Web::Helpers`.

Inside `config` there is a file called `redis.rb` which is then loaded by `reload_config`. At least it should be. Calling on `require_all` inside my `config.ru` (top level) effectively loads the content of `redis.rb`, but inside my helper module it does not.

`redis.rb` contains assignments to `configatron.redis` (which should be accessible from any scope level right?)

Another troubling fact: if I change the path I give to `require_all` it raises an exception.

Also, if I write, for example, `puts "Haaaaa!"` inside the `redis.rb`, it is executed when loaded from `config.ru` but not when loaded from `helpers.rb`.

What could be the cause of this ? If it has to do with lexical scoping, then why is it impossible to actually execute statements such as `puts` or `configatron.foo = 'hello'` ?

Note that `require_all` and `configatron` are loaded in `config.ru`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply to user `load_all` instead of `require_all`.

The code would not load not because of some lexical scoping issue but because of that `require_all` does not load twice the same file. Therefore using `load_all` solves the problem.